# Please help me with this Thumbnail in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iam trying to make Upload and make thumbail but my thumbnail just wont upload cant anyone help me ?
In my Code the file is uploaded but thumbnail is not created

Data Upload

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('gambar')) {
            // End validasi

            $data = array(
                'title'             => 'Tambah Galeri',
                'kategori_galeri'   => $kategori_galeri,
                'error'             => $this->upload->display_errors(),
                'isi'               => 'admin/galeri/tambah'
            );
            $this->load->view('admin/layout/wrapper', $data, FALSE);
```

Thumbnail code

```
$upload_data                = array('uploads' => $this->upload->data());
            // Image Editor
            $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image']     = './assets/upload/image/' . $upload_data['uploads']['file_name'];
            $config['new_image']        = './assets/upload/image/thumbs/';
            $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;
            $config['quality']          = "100%";
            $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
            $config['width']            = 500; // Pixel
            $config['height']           = 500; // Pixel
            $config['x_axis']           = 0;
            $config['y_axis']           = 0;
            $config['thumb_marker']     = '';
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Please can someone help me with this

Comment: does /upload/image/thumbs/ directory is existed? and writtable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the file paths `/assets/upload/image/` and `/assets/upload/image/thumbs/`.